# Exception of Spring in doInTransactionWithoutResult

Tags: java, spring, transactions

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.habuma.spitter.service.SpitterServiceImpl$1.doInTransactionWithoutResult(SpitterServiceImpl.java:28)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.doInTransaction(TransactionCallbackWithoutResult.java:33)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
    at com.habuma.spitter.service.SpitterServiceImpl.addTwoSpitter(SpitterServiceImpl.java:25)
    at com.habuma.spitter.test.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:25)

Comment: Post you code also,dont just copy paste your stack trace, state your problem more details. Please put some effort to get answer.